# JTextArea in JScrollPane wrapping words but missing letters

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, joptionpane

I wanted to make a `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` with some `JTextArea` and `JLabel`. 
The problem was that the dialog was too small and i didn't find any solutions, so i just decided to put my content in a `JScrollPane`.

I saw that i must put all my `JTextArea` and my `JLabel` in a `JPanel` because adding them in the `JScrollPane` in a row doesn't allow me to put the viewport correctly.

The final problem is that my JTextArea are wrapping words correctly but when i have words of 2 or 3 letters lenght, they are hide by the scrollbar.

SSCCE :

```
public class myTest extends JFrame
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new myTest();
        }
        public myTest()
        {
            String myLongString="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
            String aLittleString="I am a poor little string which is placed at the bottom of a JOptionPane.";
            String[] options = {"OK","NO"}; 

            JLabel titre1 = new JLabel("Title"); 
            JLabel titre2 = new JLabel("Title 2");

            Map<TextAttribute,Integer> attributs = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Integer>();
            attributs.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
            Font police = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12).deriveFont(attributs); 

            titre1.setFont(police);
            titre2.setFont(police);

            JTextArea text3 = new JTextArea(myLongString,5,75); 
            text3.setLineWrap(true);
            text3.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            text3.setEditable(false);
            Color back = this.getBackground();
            text3.setBackground(back);
            JTextArea text = new JTextArea(myLongString,5,75); 
            text.setLineWrap(true);
            text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            text.setEditable(false);
            text.setBackground(back);

            JTextArea text2 = new JTextArea(aLittleString,5,75); 
            text2.setLineWrap(true);
            text2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            text2.setEditable(false);
            text2.setBackground(back);
            JPanel bas = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel basbas = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            bas.add(titre1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            bas.add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            basbas.add(titre2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            basbas.add(text2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            basbas.add(text3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            bas.add(basbas,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(bas);
            js.setBorder(null);
            js.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            js.setViewportView(bas);
            JLabel lMessage = new JLabel("A message."); 

            Object[] params = {js,lMessage}; 

            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(),
                    params,
                    "my dialog", 
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null, 
                    options, 
                    options[0]); 

        }
    }
```

I read several subjects, but they are always speaking about setWrapStyleWord.
I disable the horizontal scrollbar because i don't want it, in fact i don't want a scrollbar for 2 letters off-side.

In my opinion the problem is that i construct the scrollbar with a `JPanel` but i don't find an other solution.

Any feedback on my post or my english are as well welcome.

Comment: [Writing a perfect question.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) Please do provide one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), since the snippet provided by you in not compilable in any sense :( . Just a guess, try to comment out this line `js.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);`, since your `LineWrap` property is true, you don't need that.

Comment: I will edit the SSCCE it seems i missed my c/p.
I already try without scrollbar_horizontal, but like i badly said "i don't want a scrollbar for 2 letters off-side" when i let JScrollPane by default one horizontal scrollbar appear for only 2 character off-side.

Comment: Now i got the idea, try to provide one `EmptyBorder`  to your `JPanel` to which you adding `JScrollPane` that will do what you wanted :-)

Comment: Providing `bas.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 20));` solve the problem. Thanks
But i'm still confuse about this problem of display, the scrollbar shouldn't be in conflict with the text.
BTW can you tell me if my SSCCE is well now ? although my problem is solved.

Comment: But can you provide an answer because with a comment i can't notice my problem as solved :/
edit : well for the SSCCE i was doubtful about import but ok i will provide them in the future.

Comment: @nIcEcOw *"So for me atleast the import statements are also the part of one SSCCE"*  That is what I meant when I wrote the SSCCE document. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting my comment to answer. Please do try to provide one [Empty Border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html) to your `JPanel` to which you are adding `JScrollPane`, or you can add one EmptyBorder to your `JTextArea`.

Comment: @JullenBreull : Your problem is very much like this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331129/jscrollpane-resize-containing-jpanel-when-scrollbars-appear/10333957#10333957)

Comment: My bad i remember this topic, i checked it but didn't take a look to your answer :s

Comment: Adding a border the size of the width of the scrollbar does solve the problem but I don't think it's the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the `JScrollPane` to the `JPanel` parent of a `JLabel` and a `JTextArea`. That way the `JTextArea` will think that it as a wider width than it has to render the text on.

I would suggest you to add the scroller to the `JTextArea` instead (making the scrollpane the parent). Then the textarea will know the real width (excluding scrollbars).

---

### Example:

[image: screenshot]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myLongString="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
    String[] options = {"OK","NO"}; 

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(myLongString, 5, 55); 
    text.setLineWrap(true);
    text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    text.setEditable(false);

    JPanel bas = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    bas.add(new JLabel("Title"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    bas.add(new JScrollPane(text),BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(),
            bas,
            "my dialog", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null, 
            options, 
            options[0]); 

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Well i understand, i was expecting that. However how would you do for multiple JTextArea, if i had some different component between them ?

Comment: You can add scrollbars for each of the `JTextArea`s.

Comment: But my content is linear so i need a global scrollbar, i understand your example and i think that my problem is the multiple component content.

Comment: @JulienBreuil I believe that your problem comes from an incorrect usage of multiple Textareas. You should rather try to put all your text in a single JEditorPane (or JTextPane) and include that in the JScrollPane. You also force the preferredSize of the textarea (by specifying rows and cols) but you can't be sure that the text will hold in such area, meaning that some text could get lost.